# If statement not running after extra code added in PHP

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

Hi everyone I am new to PHP and I am trying to debug but getting a problem. When I run my script it works fine and the IF statement runs correctly to tell me my password is incorrect but then when I add code below it, I no longer get the error message. I am not sure whether the screen is being cleared or the IF statement for some reason is not run. Example below

This runs fine and as the password is incorrect the IF statement runs and tells me password is incorrect.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","IncorrectPassword","DBName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }      
?>
```

Now the same code again but with some more added below it I no longer get the error message to say the IF statement has run and the password is incorrect.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","IncorrectPassword","DBName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }
$files = glob('*.mp3");
usort ($files, function ($a, $b) {
       return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});       
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is an typo in your `glob`. See the color coding, you will notice a mismatched of quotes & apostrophe.

Comment: Read up on how to implement php error handling to let you see errors in development mode and how to access error logs ...and use an IDE that helps you see syntax errors

Comment: Thanks I will look that info over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in your quotes:

```
glob('*.mp3");
```

Should be:

```
glob("*.mp3");
```

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, dumb mistake, that fixed it. I still don't understand though why it did not run the IF statement. Does it go through and do error checking first before it runs the file? I would have assumed it would run the IF then gone to the GLOB statement and thrown an error.

Comment: @NicholasMuir You're welcome! As there's a syntax error, your code won't execute further.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
glob('*.mp3");
```

Should be

```
glob("*.mp3");
```